# call mysql database in webservice

Tags: mysql, sql, web-services

I need to consume mysql database in web service.
I create small database in mysql by using wampserver, then I export this database to be `DB1.sql`.
I add this file to my web service solution and add a method to call this database, my database had one table `student` and didn't have username and password.

I've written the following code:

```
namespace WebApplication8
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment                         the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string conDb()
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("database=DB1;");
            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM student;", myConnection);
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return "pass";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                return "fail";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run this webservice and call "conDB" function it return to me "fail".
So, where is the problem please

Comment: Problem is with your connection string. You have to specify database server, user and password. You can study connection strings here https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: thanks very much for your response, but as I mentioned my database included in the web service solution, and it didn't have username and password

Comment: I Tried to connect to the database directly from the server where wampserver store files, I tried the following statements , and the same result happened , it failed to connect                             SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id='root'; password='';Server=localhost:8080;Database=BD1;");                                 or                                                                 SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id='root'; password='';Server=localhost:3306;Database=BD1;");
so what can I do please

Comment: You have to replace the localhost with IP address of the database server. Something like this ... Server=192.168.1.1:8080;